# Failed to execute linux service script with "exec format error"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I wrote a bash script to clean proxy:

```
dconf write /system/proxy/mode "'none'"
```

I can use the terminal to execute it, but I want to use it as a service, so, I wrote a service to execute it before shutdown:

```
[Unit]
Description=clean proxy
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/***/myprocess/services/logout_service.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
```

Then I enable this service. But when I restart my computer, it fails.

```
sudo journalctl -u shutdown-clean-proxy.service

3月 23 22:28:40 the-refuge systemd[1]: Starting clean proxy... 
3月 23 22:28:40 the-refuge systemd[3442]: shutdown-clean-proxy.service:
Failed to execute /home/***/myprocess/services/logout_service.sh: Exec format error 
3月 23 22:28:40 the-refuge systemd[3442]: shutdown-clean-proxy.service: **Failed at step EXEC spawning**
/home/***/myprocess/services/logout_service.sh: **Exec format error** 
3月 23 22:28:40 the-refuge systemd[1]: shutdown-clean-proxy.service: **Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC** 
3月 23 22:28:40 the-refuge systemd[1]: shutdown-clean-proxy.service: **Failed with result 'exit-code'.** 
3月 23 22:28:40 the-refuge systemd[1]: **Failed to start clean proxy.**
```

What's wrong?

when I added "dbus-launch" before the command:
dbus-launch dconf write /system/proxy/mode "'none'"

run the command directly, it's works, but the service still not work and  no error shows up:

```
3月 25 16:43:20 the-refuge dbus-daemon[2829]: [session uid=0 pid=2818] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled

3月 25 16:43:20 the-refuge systemd[1]: Starting clean proxy...

3月 25 16:43:20 the-refuge dbus-daemon[2829]: [session uid=0 pid=2818] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=2812 comm="dconf write /system/proxy/mode 'non>

3月 25 16:43:20 the-refuge dbus-daemon[2829]: [session uid=0 pid=2818] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'

3月 25 16:43:20 the-refuge systemd[1]: shutdown-clean-proxy.service: Deactivated successfully.

3月 25 16:43:20 the-refuge systemd[1]: Finished clean proxy.
```

Comment: Is there 'shebang' or 'colon' in the first line of script?

Comment: @yvs2014 only one command: dconf write /system/proxy/mode "'none'" , and I can run it successfully with terminal

Comment: try with `#!/bin/sh` in the first line of that script

Comment: @yvs2014 I added it just now, but it still fails. now the error is "error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY", can't understand what's the error means